# Removing whitespace from string in C using pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, whitespace

I'm having some issues trying to remove all whitespace from a string (for example: "a b  c    x") using a method that takes a double pointer argument. I have solved it using single pointers and using strings in c++, but I wanted to get this working as well for curiosity's sake :)

This is what I've tried:

```
void remove_whitespace(char** s)
{
    char **rd; // "read" pointer
    char **wr; // "write" pointer

    rd = wr = s; // initially, both read and write pointers point to beginning of string

    while ( *rd != 0 ) // while not at end of string
    {
    while ( isspace( **rd ) ) // while rd points to a whitespace character
        rd++;                  // advance rd
    *wr++ = *rd++;           // copy *rd to *wr, advance both pointers
    }
    *wr = 0;                   // terminate the result

    printf("\nsquished: %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: Why `char**` over `char*`?

Comment: Why are you using `char **` for a single string? You don't reassign `s` so there's no need.

Comment: This line is wrong: `rd++; ` ... and this one: `*wr = 0;`

Comment: should be `printf("\nsquished: %s\n", *s);`, `"%s"` expects a `char*`

Comment: If you need to have `char** s` you can have `char *rd, *wr; rd = wr = *s;`.

Comment: Jonas Örnfelt, post how `remove_whitespace()` is called.  Post a  [mcve].

Comment: Jonas Örnfelt, Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: You want to modify the string pointed to by `*s`, I assume. The problem here is that with `rd = wr = s` all these three pointers point to exactly the same pointer which itself points to the string. If you now modify the single pointee (e.g. `++*rd`) then this change gets visible to *all* of the pointers, i.e. after `++*rd;` the equation `**rd == **rw` still holds true even if no single character is the same. Actually this change even gets visible to the pointer by which the function was called.

Comment: Assuming you revert your implementation back to single pointer, then still there's a critical issue with: trailing whitespace! The nested loop will continue then until `*rd == 0` as the null-terminator is no whitespace. This one will be copied to `*wr` and then finally `*wr = 0;` writes another null terminator beyond. No harm, in worst case (single trailing WS) the null-terminator already there will be overwritten. In any case `rd`, after the loop, points to one after the null-terminator – which still is valid (one past the end of the entire array) and fine as long as you do not dereference.

Comment: Indeed, all is fine with, but it's more difficult to verify than a much simpler variant of: `while(*rd) { if(!isspace((unsigned char)*rd) { *wr++ = *rd; } ++rd; }` Note, too, the cast to unsigned char to avoid undefined behaviour on `char` being signed and holding a character in the range of [128, 255).

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to modify the string pointed to by *s, as mentioned above. Hence the pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

All errors in this function stem from confusing the level of indirection.  Using `char**` over `char*` increases the level of indirection which affects every usage of these variables.

Simply converting the function to use `char*` makes it much clearer:

```
void remove_whitespace(char* s)
{
    char *rd; // "read" pointer
    char *wr; // "write" pointer

    rd = wr = s; // initially, both read and write pointers point to beginning of string

    while ( *rd != 0 ) // while not at end of string
    {
        if (isspace( *rd ) ) // while rd points to a whitespace character
        {
            rd++;                  // advance rd
            continue;
        }
        *wr++ = *rd++;           // copy *rd to *wr, advance both pointers
    }
    *wr = 0;                   // terminate the result

    printf("\nsquished: %s\n", s);
}
```

Comment: In the first version, `*wr++;` and `*rd++;` should be `(*wr)++;` and `(*rd)++;`.

Comment: *'Here is a correct version while keeping `char**`'* – have you tested? This looks pretty suspicious to me: `*rd++;` increments the *pointee* of `rd`, but due to `rd = wr = s;` this is the same pointee than the one of `wr`, so you increment `*wr` right with it, and actually `*s`, too!

Comment: You guys are correct.  Fixed.

Comment: There is still one uncorrected `*rd++;`. Also, @Aconcagua's point about `*s` being modified still holds.

Comment: Probably best just to get rid of the first version. It's neither correct nor useful!

Comment: @IanAbbott  That is why it is so broken.  Wasn't thinking it would be used.  I just noticed the `rd = wr = s;` thing in a debugger.  Just goes to show why *not* to do this lol.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is good if function returns something.
2. Your local worker pointers do not have to be pointers to pointers

```
char **remove_whitespace(char **s)
{
    char *rd; // "read" pointer
    char *wr; // "write" pointer

    rd = wr = *s; 

    while ( *rd) // while not at end of string
    {
    while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*rd ) ) // while rd points to a whitespace character
        rd++;                  // advance rd
    *wr++ = *rd++;           // copy *rd to *wr, advance both pointers
    }
    *wr = 0;                   // terminate the result

    printf("\nsquished: %s\n", *s);
    return s;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    char z[] = "asdas das as \r dfds \n dsa \t";
    char *p = z;

    remove_whitespace(&p);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ex337TE6n

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. How did you call the function?

Comment: @JonasÖrnfelt because you do not pass pointer to pointer. READ THE WARNINGS IN YOUR CODE!!!!  If you pass `&z` it will not give pointer to pointer only pointer to array and it is not thee same

Comment: *'Your local worker pointers do not have to be pointers to pointers'* – actually even: *'must not'* – at least if initialised as in the question...

Comment: `It is good if function returns something.` Depends... In many cases convenient, but opens the question: Is the string returned a copy (i.e. does it have to be `free`d) or is the modification in place? Sure, documentation needs to reveal that anyway, but a void return type would automatically imply the latter (self-documenting code)...

Comment: Ah, okay. I was calling it with:
char* test = "a b c ";
remove_whitespace(&test);

Comment: You can't modify the string literal.